# Checking state of variable in one running script from another script in python

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Q: How do i access the value of a variable running in one python script from another script

Eg: I have two files:

script1.py:

```
foo = 0

if __name__ = '__main__':
    while True:
        foo += 1
```

script2.py:

```
import script1 as s1

if __name__ = '__main__':
    while True:
        print s1.foo
```

now, i run script1.py as:

```
python script1.py
```

and script2.py as:

```
python script2.py
```

but the problem is that script2.py will constantly print 0 as foo is initialised to 0. i want script2 to print the value of foo as it is being modified. How do I do this? Is it even possible?